# Check message source in Jms - Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, spring-jms

In our application we have configured our jms queue in weblogic and sending messages as ByteMessage after converting the object to byte array.

We are reading messages from the queue in asynchronous manner using onMessge method.

As we are sending the messages as byte message so in receiving end we are parsing the Message object to ByteMessage. But here for some of the messages we are getting ClassCastException.

We are not able to find out from where these messages are coming and how to stop them. We are also setting Jms type to identify that these messages are sent by us, but for these messages jms type is coming as null.

Anyone has any idea how to fix it?

**Exception**:

```
weblogic.jms.common.ObjectMessageImpl can not be cast to javax.jms.ByteMessage
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're sending your messages as `BytesMessage`? `ObjectMessageImpl` is the Weblogic implementation of an `ObjectMessage`. Are you putting messages onto a queue using a protocol other than WebLogic's default one? I see problems like this a lot when message brokers are handling multiple wire protocols.

Comment: @KevinBoone may i know how to find out the protocol details? For sending i am converting them to ByteMessage before calling the send method and passing this object. When i was using ObjectMessage i was getting an exception in OnMessge ClassNotFoundException:org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet. The object we are sending has a one to may mapping using Set